# C++ - updating values on maps

Tags: c++

```
struct Instrument
{
   std::string   make;
   std::string   brand;
   double   age;
   Instrument(std::string const& f, std::string const& s, double   l) { BLABLA }
   bool operator<(Instrumentconst& rhs) { return BLABLABLA;}
};
std::map<int,Instrument>   instMap;

Instrument myObj();
instMap.insert(pair<int,Instrument>(10,myObj));
```

If I need to update a value in this map for individual attributes separately.
Would we be creating copies of Instrument every time we retrieve it from map to update it?

```
it = instMap.lower_bound(10);
if (it != m.end())
    *(it->second).brand = "Jonas";<= will there be a copy of Instrument object created here?
```

Is this the most memory(and time) efficient way to update values - if this operation had to be done on a million entries?

We are using C++ 98.

Comment: Please give some [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your code, as presented wouldn't even compile. Your `std::map` (`std::map<int,Instrument>   instMap;`) stores instances of objects, while you are trying to insert into it by calling `new`, which returns a pointer. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Disregarding the typos, you would invoke the `std::string` constructor for `const char*` and invoke the copy assignment operator. There is no shortcut/faster way in C++98.

Comment: `*(it->second).brand = "Jonas";` will invoke a copy constructor of std::string, so yes you're technically copying the string but it's nothing to worry about from performance side of view.

Comment: You are wasting everyone time with your code that don't even compiles. If you want help, then at least make some minimal efforts.

Comment: If you want efficiency, then upgrade your compiler! First C++ 11 and up have move semantic and a more optomized STL. Second, if you are still using C++98, then your compiler generate code for CPU of 20 years ago. Finally, measure the performance yourself before assuming you need to optimize that code further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is no, the Instrument object will not be copied.

The `std::string` will be copied, at least in c++98.